# how to display multiple pictures on GLSurface view using Android ndk

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glsurfaceview

I am able to display an image using OpenGL ES in android ndk. now I want to display 2 or four images using multithreading in OPENGL ES through android ndk.
I have done huge search for this and came to know a Surfaceview can only have one picture. Then what is the way to display multiple pictures on GLSurface view..

Can anybody please tell me how it can be done..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I will try to rephrase your need. Correct me if i am wrong : you want to display 2 or 4 textures? Currently, you tried to add 2 or 4 GLSurfaceView, each one displaying one texture, that's it?

Comment: @rockeye thanks for reply... What I want to do multithreading to display 2 or 4 images..should it possible with displaying multiple textures?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are several issues here.

First of all, if you are trying to display "pictures" through OpenGL(ES), you mean **textures** (OpenGL readable format for "pictures" or "image"), right ? If you are not sure of what I am talking about, find some tutorial about displaying images using OpenGLES. Learn how to display juste 1 and you will be able to display 4.

> a Surfaceview can only have one picture

You may have misunderstand something. A GLSurfaceView can draw as many textures as your video memory can handle.

Basically, to display your textures, you will draw 2 or 4 quads and bind the appropriate textures to them.

About the multithreading, I guess you gather your pictures asynchronously. Just wait for a complete picture, and while in the OpenGL thread, create a texture and bind it to a quad.